# Conditionally add properties to an object if referencing variable contains string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Some state

```
const [submittedSev, setSubmittedSev] = useState('');
const [newSev, setNewSev] = useState('');
```

Mixpanel events where I'm sending properties that may or may not exist. Sometimes the `submittedSev` and `newSev` may be empty strings but this will still send

```
mixpanel.track('COMPLETED', {
    response: props.details.title,
    submittedSev,
    newSev
});
```

I'd like to only add `submittedSev` and `newSev` properties if the string isn't empty. For sure I could set up a conditional statement and check the string length and send a different Mixpanel event but that doesn't seem succinct enough.

Output of data that sometimes gets sent

```
{
 "response": "hello",
 "submittedSev": "",
 "newSev": ""
}
```

How can I only add properties to object if they are not empty strings?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a really concise way to do it using the spread `...` operator and evaluating an expression with the AND operator `&&` which returns the second value if the first is truthy:

```js
// Example.js
const name = ''
const email = 'asd@gmail.com'
const phone = ''

const output = {
 ...(name && {name}),
 ...(email && {email}),
 ...(phone && {phone})
}

console.log(output)
```

So for your code it'd be:

```
mixpanel.track('COMPLETED', {
    response: props.details.title,
    ...(submittedSev && {submittedSev}),
    ...(newSev && {newSev})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could centralize the logic that sends the events in a separate function, and go through the properties of the event object and filter out the ones that are not empty strings:

```js
function trackMixpanelEvent(eventType, event) {
  const keys = Object.keys(event).filter(
     key => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(event, key));
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (event[key] === '') {
      delete event[key];
    }
  });
  mixpanel.track(eventType, event);
}
```

And then just call it without worrying which properties are empty strings:

```js
trackMixpanelEvent('COMPLETED', {
    response: props.details.title,
    submittedSev,
    newSev
});
```